# Apache not serving assets - Rails 5, Puma, Apache, Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't get css and js to render with Apache for my Rails 5 app running Puma. I've seen similar questions asked about this issue but none have worked for me so I think it might be specific to this stack or because I'm missing something about the location match in my httpd-vhosts.conf file. Here's what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName clientdb
DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.7-0/projects/clientdb/public/"
<Directory "C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.2.7-0/projects/clientdb/public/" >
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://puma_cluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3004
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
ProxyPass /robots.txt !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(404|422|500).html$ !
ProxyPass /assets/ !

ProxyPass / balancer://puma_cluster/
# enumerate all nodes for proxypassreverse since it adds a trailing slash :( bugid 51982
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3003
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3004

# ProxyPass / balancer://puma_cluster/ lbmethod=byrequests
# ProxyPass / balancer://puma_cluster/ lbmethod=bytraffic
# ProxyPass / balancer://puma_cluster/ lbmethod=bybusyness

<FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.js\.gz$>
    ForceType text/javascript
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>

<Location /assets/>
    # Use of ETag is discouraged when Last-Modified is present
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    # RFC says only cache for 1 year
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Location>


<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*\.(css|js)$">
    RewriteEngine on

    # Make sure the browser supports gzip encoding before we send it,
    # and that we have a precompiled .gz version.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.gz
</LocationMatch>

    # Make sure Content-Type is set for 'real' type, not gzip,
    # and Content-Encoding is there to tell browser it needs to
    # unzip to get real type.

    # Make sure Vary header is set; while apache docs suggest it
    # ought to be set automatically by our RewriteCond that uses an HTTP
    # header, does not seem to be reliably working.
<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*\.css\.gz$">
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header add Vary Accept-Encoding
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*\.js\.gz$">
    ForceType application/javascript
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header add Vary Accept-Encoding
</LocationMatch>
```

And this is config/environments/production.rb. (I have tried both enabling and disabling the static file server and neither works)

```
    Rails.application.configure do
   # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in 
   config/application.rb.

   # Code is not reloaded between requests.
   config.cache_classes = true

     # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
     # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
     # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
     # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
     config.eager_load = true
     config.threadsafe!

     # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
     config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
     config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

     # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default 
     since
     # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
     # config.public_file_server.enabled = 
        ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
     config.public_file_server.enabled = false
     # config.public_file_server.enabled = true

     # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
     # config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
     # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

     # config.assets.prefix = '/clientdb/public/assets'
     # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = false
     # added by KO to try fix for serving assets on apache
     # config.assets.digest = true
     # config.assets.debug = true
     # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset 
     server.
     # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'
     # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
     config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
```

What am I missing here? I'm able to get bootstrap to render using the CDN but the rest is still missing and ideally I'd like to keep my asset pipeline intact. If I have to use CDN's then so be it, but I feel like this it probably just a tweak.

Comment: did you precompile assets? Also, check in apache error log.

Comment: I did precompile. The apache error log gives me a 404 `::1 - - [19/Jun/2017:10:53:28 -0700] "GET /assets/application-bf6cbb6f0c09a957960ba20c6fbb218367fc97c5703bd7e623e3e9ebb381e611.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1722`

Comment: My last comment was the access.log. The error.log shows this `[Mon Jun 19 10:52:36.092091 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2120:tid 392] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor` @Rishav Rastogi

Answer (score 1):

You need a "/" at the end of your ProxyPassReverse statements.

A similar question was asked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929360/4038302